# why not connect to database mysql if in jelastic hosting,and if in eclipse normal?

Tags: hosting, jelastic

message

> Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 

    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd

        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.hendri" />

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->

    <!--  <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/> -->
        <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/"/>
        <mvc:resources mapping="/bukanadmin/**" location="/bukanadmin/"/>
        <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>





    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver">

        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">

        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://mysql3309-testaja.kilatiron.com:3306/sms" />       
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="somepassword" />
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>



    </bean>





    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />



        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.hendri.domain" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>



</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat provided with a memory leak detection feature, when there's a JDBC 4.0 compatible driver in the webapp's /WEB-INF/lib which auto-registers itself during webapp's startup using the ServiceLoader API, but which did not auto-deregister itself during webapp's shutdown. 
You can move the [JDBC driver](http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.zip) to Tomcat's /lib folder (/opt/tomcat/lib) and have a connection pooled datasource to manage the driver.

**Note** that Tomcat's builtin DBCP does not deregister drivers properly on close.

See also bug [DBCP-322](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DBCP-332).